# Extracting Domains from URL in EmEditor or NotePad++

Tags: notepad++, extract

Suppose I have a list of domains mixed with subdomains
As shown below;

```
sub1.domain1.com
sub2.domain2.com
sub3.domain3.com
```

and I want to extract just the domains from the list to give the preferred output as

```
domain1.com
domain2.com
domain3.com
```

Comment: - [FAQ Desk: Where to find REGEX documentation ? | Notepad++ Community](https://community.notepad-plus-plus.org/topic/15765/faq-desk-where-to-find-regex-documentation)
 - [Notepad++: A guide to using regular expressions and extended search mode](http://markantoniou.blogspot.co.uk/2008/06/notepad-how-to-use-regular-expressions.html)
 - [Regular Expressions Tutorial](http://www.regular-expressions.info/tutorial.html)
 - [RegExr: Learn, Build, & Test RegEx](http://regexr.com/)
 - [regex101: Online regex tester and debugger](https://regex101.com/)

Comment: I'm sure you've noticed by now that [one of your earlier questions](https://superuser.com/q/1774410/214658) has been closed. There are reasons for this. Please also read the comments there and all the links given above here. Please note for future questions that superuser.com is not a free script/code writing service. If you tell us what you have tried so far (include the scripts/code you are already using) and where you are stuck then we can try to help with specific problems. Again - if an answer has helped you solve your problem feel free to mark the answer as accepted.

Answer (score 0):

Lets say you have your URL list or some more lines in a text file line by line

```
sub1.domain1.com
sub22.domain2.com
sub333.domain3.com

Ragnit
Lengwethen
Rautenberg
```

you'd go through following steps when using Notepad++:

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>
- Find what: `^.+\.([^.]+\.[^.]+)$`
- Replace with: `\1`
- Tick the *Wrap around* option
- Search mode: *Regular expression*
- Click on <kbd>Replace All</kbd> (at your own risk)

Please note this won't work with country code top level domains which use third-level registration like `example.gov.uk`